# Issue in i carousel and my custom animation

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uianimation, icarousel

i've created d app where app starts an image have to be animated and my buttons will be displayed in coverflow effect using icarousel..Here is my code

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
carousel.type = iCarouselTypeInvertedWheel              ;

CGRect ChaintopFrame = Chaintop.frame;
ChaintopFrame.origin.y = self.view.bounds.size.height;    
//CGRect ChainbottomFrame = Chainbottom.frame;
//ChainbottomFrame.origin.y = self.view.bounds.size.height;

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                      delay:1.0
                    options: UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{
                  Chaintop.frame = ChaintopFrame;
                     //Chainbottom.frame = ChainbottomFrame;
                 } 
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     NSLog(@"Done!");
                 }];
}


- (UIView *)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel viewForItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index reusingView:(UIView *)view
{

   UIImage *buttonImage=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Cover_0.png"],
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"Cover_1.png"],
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"Cover_2.png"],
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"Cover_3.png"],
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"Cover_4.png"],
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"Cover_5.png"],
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"Cover_6.png"],
                      [UIImage imageNamed:@"Cover_7.png"],nil];

UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200.0f, 200.0f);

[button setImage:(UIImage*)[buttonImage objectAtIndex:index] forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 

[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
return button;



 }
```

Now when i run my simulator the image which used for animation went back and the buttons are displayed front.The good thing is animation inn image is working...and i resized my icarousel view too...

Am i missing anything?...

Comment: how about adding the image first then add the button frame.

Comment: u mean to say animating image and button frame or button image

Comment: your making a buttoned image that can be clicked and will do a corresponding action right?

Comment: yes.but my issue is the animating image goes back while the buttons are in front...Animation is happening at back of icarousel buttons...icarousel is another view which i resized and placed it in UIView...

Comment: how about adding the image as view's subview? And are you allocating the image?

Comment: like [self.view addsubview:UIView or icarousel];?...

Comment: How do you add your image or allocate it?

Comment: i allocated it in xib not in code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your adding your `imageView` wrong in your `iCarousel` view,
try this:

```
[self.view addSubview:Chaintop];
```

and try resizing your image.

hope this helps.

Comment: i have another problem...that animating image loads whenever the particular viewcontroller loads..but i need only at my app starts?..

Comment: like a splash screen? you should put it you app delegate.

Comment: after displaying the image put an NSTimer then display the image.

Comment: i think NSTimer is only used to display time...Is it/

Comment: No you can use it in different purposes. How about ask another question then ill answer it there.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13173/discussion-between-dany-and-kobe-o4)